# How to aggregate results based on all distinct combinations in a column?

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, aggregate

I have a table where I try to aggreate results (Sum) based on all possible combinations of Product_Ids per Order (Order_Id). Anybody that can guide me here?

[image]

I'm a bit lost here, but I have tried to group the different combinations but don't manage to get the right results.

Comment: and what's the results if you add this record ? order_id = 2 and product_id = 'A' and sum = 10 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you would like to group the results by `order_id`:

```
select array_agg(distinct product_id), sum(summ) total 
from stat 
group by order_id
order by total desc;
```

The function `array_agg(distinct product_id)` helps to concatenate unique values of `product_id` grouping values by `order_id`.

See the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yvcupren) with all the details.